# Looking for specific UI controls on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create most effective UI for entering trailer inspection data.

THere is 8 wheels :) And for each wheel driver need to specify:

1. Thread Depth - this goes in predefined values. Ideally I like some kind of up/down and view so driver can specify 5/6/7 instead of typing
2. PSI - pressure. Same thing. Some kind of scroller or up/down numerical thingy?
3. Tire brand - I will use Spinner for this.

Do you have any control suggestion for #1/2 ? I'm looking for something built-in but if not - I will appreciate pointer to source code of similar control

Thanks!

Comment: 1. TextView with 2 buttons for up down.
2. Spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with "up/down numerical thingys" is that they either aren't finger-friendly or are large. If you are planning on having all eight tires on one phone screen, size is an issue.

If you are limiting this to Honeycomb and higher, `NumberPicker` is available for the "up/down numerical thingy". But, again, it's large. `SeekBar` plus a `TextView` for the actual selected value is another possibility, one that will take up less screen space.

If you are going to use a `Spinner` for brand, be sure to have an "Other" option.

Comment: I was hoping for easy answer. I'm going to create my own control and have button-textview-button - so buttons will be on each side with +/- I'm coding for 2.1 and numberpicker is not there

Answer (score 0):

A data entry application/UI needs to be as easy to use as possible. If it is being used by truckers in rough environments, potentially in bright sunlight, with drivers wearing gloves, etc then the UI needs to be big, and extremely easy to use. By "big" I mean a typical smart phone sized screen should have, for example, the PSI number in large text in the middle of the screen and up/down rockers above/below (for portrait) or left/right for landscape. This way its easy to read, easy to manipulate and almost foolproof.

The UI can then be something as simple as two image views (up/down) rockers and a text view to display the current reading, and maybe an OK button. Put this in a separate activity and have that activity fill the parent view, ideally the whole screen.

Thus instead of a single UI view, perhaps you should consider multiple Activities for each sub screen and have a "home" activity that pictorially shows what has been gathered, what data has still to be gathered, and perhaps an indication of a problem - depending on your application's requirements/purpose.

Opinion: if the inspection is very procedural (left front tire, left rear tractor tire, left outer rear trailer tire, left inner trailer tire, etc) then the UI should "flow" in accordance with that procedure.